# About to buy my first Raspberry Pi; what should I look for in an SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I am going to purchase a Pi 3 B+ (probably from Element 14).

I have been reading about SD card "Wear Leveling". Do all the reputable (Samsung EVO, etc) use some form of wear leveling?
I read somewhere that the max capacity the Pi 3 B+ can use is 64 GB, but I read about people using 128 GB cards.
From what I read, the larger card (with wear leveling) will last longer.

Should I look for an SD card with wear levelling, and what capacity should I look for? Are there any other factors to consider when choosing an SD card?

Comment: Shopping advice is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi has no upper limit on SD card size. I strongly suggest 8 GB or more, you are likely to run out of space otherwise.

All consumer SD cards on the market do wear leveling. The algorithms are top-secret and have a weakness: They do not cope well with random R/W access at all.

**The SD card association introduced "Application Performance Classes" in November 2016 to address this. Those specially designated cards are likely to have better performance than regular class 10  or UHS-I cards under (Raspbian) Linux, too.**

Comment: Which "Application Performance Class" should one use?; i.e. how do you know which SD card to use - are they marked or designated in some way?

Comment: AFAIK only AP1 and AP2 have been defined till date. AP2 has more IOPS, so it should be better ...

Answer (score -1):

[This post](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/raspberry-pi-microsd-card-performance-comparison-2018) notes:

> One of the highest-impact upgrades you can perform to increase
>   Raspberry Pi performance is to buy the fastest possible microSD
>   card—especially for applications where you need to do a lot of random
>   reads and writes.

It goes on to benchmark different brands and models of cards.

Comment: I decided on the Santek Extreme 64GB. I purchased it along with my Pi 3 b+ CanaKit from Amazon (sold and shipped by Amazon). I may add a USB SSD later.